# Is it possible to install Sitecore in Client Only mode on CD server with private IP not public IP of Database Server?

Tags: installation

For Sitecore 8.1 , is it anyhow possible to install Sitecore in Client only mode on CD using Private IP of Remote SQL instance Database server during installation, if Database server and CD server are in same network ?

Of course with public IP there is no issue at all, have installed many times but the requirement is that Database server should not have public IP preferably.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , it is possible even with private IP if database server and webserver CD are in the same network.

Your Database server should allow remote connection , I followed this post for that !

https://medium.com/@nishancw/how-to-enable-remote-connections-to-sql-server-dc5b6c812b5